# C++ remove and return pointer to object in vector iteration

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, iterator

I have a recursive function. I wish for it to return a pointer to an element of a vector but also remove that element from said vector. Something along these lines:

```
std::vector<T> vec;
...
void my_get(T* t)
{
    if(blah())
    {
        my_get(t);
    } else
    {
        for(std::vector<T>::iterator it=vec.begin(); it!=vec.end(); ++it)
        {
            if(blah_blah(*it))
            {
                // the essence of what I would like to achieve:
                t=it;
                erase(it);

                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How might I achieve this? Presumably once the element is removed from the vector, the pointer will no longer point to anything? Would I need to clone the element into an object on the heap first?

Comment: There might be a solution if you explain what you really want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
T copy_of_t = *it;
erase(it);
```

> Would I need to clone the element into an object on the heap first?

You do need to copy it yes. But in C++, you don't usually need to think about "the heap" explicitly. If you want to deal with things of type `T`, then just deal with things of type `T`. Don't get distracted by `*T` any more than you must.

*Update*: To explicitly create a copy on the heap, you can do this:

```
T* pointer_to_copy = new T(*it);
```

Comment: Thanks. How do you recommend I return copy_of_t from the function? The reason I have opted for the out-pointer is because I presume that simply returning the object will involve lots of needless copies (since the function is recursive). But is that the case?

Comment: I forgot about the recursive aspect of your function. I've updated my answer to show how to make a safer copy. But you will then need to remember to `delete` it again. Or perhaps, it might be best to use a `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`.  Finally, don't forget that, due to [RVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization), your compiler may be able to optimize the copies, and therefore returning by value might be best

Answer (score 0):

> I wish for it to return a pointer to an element of a vector but also remove that element from said vector.

Not a good idea. Once you remove the element from the vector, there is no guarantee that the pointer will be valid. If you access such a pointer, you'll have a program that will exhibit undefined behavior.

Don't do it.

Comment: Yes, it didn't smell right to me. Any suggestions on how else I might return an object from a vector and also remove it?

Comment: @lemon, you already have a copy of the object in`*t`. I am not sure why you need to get the object from the `vector` to make a copy. You can make a copy from `*t` just as easily.